# Fetch two table data in single query and data should include only that row which has max rank

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have two table **users(id,name,email) and** **comments(id,user_id,rank,content)**. In comments table i have **user_id** as foreign key for user table. Now i want to join users table with comments table and want to get all user table data along with comment data(id,rank,content) with highest rank only. I tried mysql MAX function but the data return is not correct. Can someone guide how i can achieve this.

Input :

> Table 1: users with attributes id, name, email
>
> Table 2: comments with attributes id, user_id, rank, content

Output : User table data with comment table alongside having highest rank.

> user_id | name  | email | comment_id | rank | comment |

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql here? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using an join to a derived table that has the highest ranks.

```
select u.id, u.name, u.email, c.id, c.rank, c.content
from users u
inner join comments c on u.id = c.user_id
inner join 
(select user_id, max(rank) as highest_rank from comments group by user_id) as x
on x.user_id = c.user_id and x.highest_rank = c.rank
```

Here i'm using the derived table x to record the highest comment rank for each user, and then using that to limit the comment that is returned.

This is for Postgresql

Comment: It will be valid for MySQL too